# How to check within if statement if at least one objects specific proeperty in List<T> is set

Tags: c#

I have a list of the following object

```
public class Task
{
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ProjectWorkspaceUrl { get; set; }
}
```

I want to check within an If-statement if at least one object of type Task within my list of objects (call it `TaskList`) has the property `ProjectWorkspaceUrl` filled with a string.

Is this possible? How cani do that?

Comment: Are you looking to implement some kind of object change tracking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the LINQ `Any` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx)) method to determine if, well, *any* element in a collection satisfies a condition:

```
TaskList.Any(t => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.ProjectWorkspaceUrl))
```

If you have a `List<T>` you can also use `Exists` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca(v=vs.110).aspx)) which does the same thing:

```
TaskList.Exists(t => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.ProjectWorkspace.Url))
```

Comment: And before the advent of Linq one used the `Exists` instance method (on `List<>`).

Comment: Jeppe: Can you give a short sample on that please?

Comment: @STORM Don't forget to use @ syntax when responding to a user; I added an example

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
var TaskList = new List<Task>();
//list is populated here, however you're gonna do that

//this is a boolean, in case that's not clear
var isProjectWorkspaceUrlPopulated = TaskList.Any(q => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(q.ProjectWorkspaceUrl));

if(isProjectWorkspaceUrlPopulated)
  {
    //...something happens, one supposes
  }
 else
  {
   //.... maybe something else?
  }
```